# AMD: Having two modules depend on each other

Tags: architecture, requirejs, amd

I have a Backbone application module called `app.js`, which looks something like this:

```
// module: app
define([
  'Marionette',
  'collections/links'
], function (Marionette, Links) {

  var app = Marionette.Application()

  app.addInitializer(function () {
    new Links()
  })

  return app

})
```

The `app` module creates an instance of `Marionette.Application` and adds the appropriate initialisers. One of these is to create an instance of my `Links` collection.

However, my `collections/links` module is dependant on the `app` module for its observer system.

```
// module: collections/links
define([
  'app',
  'Backbone'
], function (app, Backbone) {

  var Links = Backbone.Collection.Extend({
    initialize: function () {
      // Outputs undefined
      console.log(app)
      // This then wouldn't work because app hasn't been initialised:
      // app.on('someEvent', function () {})
    }
  })

  return Links

})
```

As this module is listed as a dependency of `app`, and `app` is a dependency of this module, I've found myself with recursive dependencies. In the end, RequireJS appears to initialise the `collections/links` module before `app` is loaded.

How can I design my application using AMD so that `app` can use my `collections/links` module and `collections/links` can use my `app` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then, you should create two modules out of `app`: the event manager, and the *initializer*.

The problem is that your `app` module ain't modular (it hasn't a single task/concern), it's a bunch of code threw together.

BTW, as of Backbone 0.9.9, `Backbone` object is a global event manager. Plus, creating your own is pretty easy: `_.extend({}, Backbone.Events)`.